# I want to extend existing Ruby gem. How can I patch it locally?

Tags: ruby, open-source, github, rubygems

There is a open source gem hosted on github.

I have found a bug and want to fix it and send pull request back.
Now this gem is locally installed.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Why marked as off topic?

Answer (score 1):

Brilliantly answered at [Forking a gem for a Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582728/forking-a-gem-for-a-rails-project/3838061#3838061).(hint: use Bundler locally)