# How to get a specific "commit" of a gem from github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm using [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin), and since it is in (very) active development, bugs turn up every now and then.

There are no versions for the gem as far as I can tell, for the gem in github, so I can't use the `:version` key for the gem declaration in the Gemfile .

Is there a way I can "tie" a specific commit(that I know is working fine for me) to the Gemfile ?

I currently have in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_admin', 
  :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this (example "commit_id"):

```
gem 'rails_admin', 
  :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git',
  :commit_id => "4e7d53e3c5c4c3c5c43c3"
```

Is this possible to do with github?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Any of these should work:

```
gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :ref => '4aded'

gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :branch => '2-3-stable'

gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :tag => 'v2.3.5'
```

Source: [How to install gems from git repositories](http://bundler.io/guides/git.html#how-to-install-gems-from-git-repositories)

Comment: Simply because all of them (and `.git/HEAD`) are refs in git :). More: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References

Answer (score 78):

A shorter version:

```
gem 'rails', :github => 'rails/rails', :ref => '4aded'
```

Or, in Ruby 1.9+

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', ref: '4aded'
```

Comment: And setting the github default source to https with that: `git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end`