# Github: cloning an older version of an Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

There's a Rails forum gem I like called Forem  https://github.com/radar/forem  However, the gem author made some changes to it that negatively impact my intended use. He added a moderation tool, whereby all new/unapproved users need their first post approved before it's displayed to the forum. This essentially mean that a moderator needs to be present all the time or the forum will have a hard time get going. This is a recent addition to the app.

Since github is version control, I'm wondering if there's a way to clone or use (I just want to use it, not modify it) an older version of the gem so I can use a version before the moderation was added.

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: Do you need to clone the gem or do you just need to be able to use the gem?  If you're using Bundler then you can specify the version, commit, or branch you want to use in your Gemfile.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119946/how-to-get-a-specific-commit-of-a-gem-from-github

Comment: I don't need to clone it, just use it. But I thought I'd need to clone it.

Comment: If you just want to use it, all you have to do is put it in your Gemfile and bundle!  Usually, I think you only bother to clone it if you wanted to actually change the code and submit a pull request with your improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options (all goes into `Gemfile`):

```
gem 'forem', github: 'radar/forem', ref: 'ref that you want'
```

or

```
gem 'forem', github: 'radar/forem', tag: 'tag that you want'
```

or

```
gem 'forem', github: 'radar/forem', branch: 'branch that you want'
```

All of it is described in [`Gemfile` docs](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html)