# Installing a gem using a commit's hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems, bundler

I have really simple `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
gem 'stripe-ruby-mock', 
  github: 'mnin/stripe-ruby-mock', 
  require: 'stripe_mock', 
  ref: 'b6446fb5ae2b14b6703554cbea4ebd466e4f3c47'
```

When I run `bundle` command to install this gem I get this error:

```
root@6bcff6bf3997:/app# bundle
The git source `git://github.com/mnin/stripe-ruby-mock.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
Fetching git://github.com/mnin/stripe-ruby-mock.git
fatal: Could not parse object 'b6446fb5ae2b14b6703554cbea4ebd466e4f3c47'.
Revision b6446fb5ae2b14b6703554cbea4ebd466e4f3c47 does not exist in the repository git://github.com/mnin/stripe-ruby-mock.git. Maybe you misspelled it?
```

But I can visit the commit's page on Github using this link https://github.com/mnin/stripe-ruby-mock/commit/b6446fb5ae2b14b6703554cbea4ebd466e4f3c47.

So how can I the gem using this commit's hash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install gem from GitHub source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119946/how-to-get-a-specific-commit-of-a-gem-from-github)

Comment: why do you need that particular commit if it was merged into master branch as seen in (the pull request)(https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock/pull/623) ?

Comment: @AlexanderSantos I'm not really sure. I have a project with tests. Using exactly this commit of the gem tests pass. When I use another revision - tests fail. That's why ‍♂️ I just can't get what I miss using this revision. I have this revision cached on my computer and all works fine but when I run `bundle` on another computer Bundler can't fetch the gem according Gemfile

Comment: Tag it, and get it by tag instead of commit

Comment: but that commit has been merged in to the main repo so did you try with just using `https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock`  without branch or commit?  In fact try to comment out everything and just use the core gem? It's bad practice to use forks of a gem if you can get the main repo to work. I

Answer (score 1):

That commit is not reachable from any branch or tag. For that reason, when you clone the repo from GitHub (which Bundler does under the hood), your local copy will not have that commit.

Thus, you can't use it.

On GitHub, you can see that this commit is not reachable as it doesn't list any branch or tag that contains it:

[image]

Compare that to the parent commit, which lists as being reachable from master:

[image]

Note that orphaned commits would get garbage collected by Git eventually. GitHub though doesn't do that as there might be references to particular commits.

Comment: You've provided an answer which addresses the problem, but doesn't offer a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try not to use forked gem if possible.  But if you need to lock a forked version, make sure you own the fork.  Fork the forked branch, merge it to your own repo's main branch, and then just use that repo in your gemfile.