# Guide to forking and working on a rails gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, github, rubygems, pull-request

I am looking for some kind of guide that will help me start forking gems, changing them where I need and write the complementary code to that (tests,etc) and explain the pull request procedure in github

Assuming I know rails ruby and rspec, I am missing the know-how on how a gem works, what each files means and how I should go about changing anything in it, and in what way should I work - Should I create a new rails project especially for that? or work on the gem in my original project?

For example, I want to add a simple attribute to that migration that the gem creates with a generator, but I am not sure where to start adding it, and what to do next in regards to the gem files.

A link to somewhere that explains it would be superb.. google wasn't very helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you search for how to create a gem first. "[Make your own gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/)" will help you start.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful on its own but its really basic, and doesn't help me understand the gem in specific to rails (not just ruby). Thanks again

Comment: In that case look here http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/how-rails-3-enables-more-choices-part-1 'Adding Your Own Rake Tasks', 'Adding a Custom Generator'

Answer (score 3):

I don't think guidance that you describe exists or can be written. The reason
is simple: Gems can be implemented very differently. All I can recommend it is
try to find some gems on github.com with very basic implementations, for
example ones that were written for self-educational purposes, then read and
experiment with them.

I myself recently searched with similar intentions and I found
[acts_as_commentable](https://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable) very helpful.

UPDATE:

About the "pull request" procedure on GitHub: This video can be useful [Intro to GitHub Pull Requests](http://vimeo.com/41045197)
and of course the GitHub [Fork A Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) and [Using Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find answers close to your question:

- "[Forking a gem for a Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582728/forking-a-gem-for-a-rails-project)"
- "[Fork Support](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org/wiki/Fork-Support)" on GitHub may also be helpful.