# How to efficiently fork a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I found a useful gem ([here's the link](https://github.com/prat0318/json_resume) if you're curious). I installed it using `sudo gem install json_resume`. Now it resides on `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json_resume-1.0.4/` (Mac OS). However, I needed to change some of its elements. So far I changed them in the `/Library` directly. This is obviously not the best way.

I'd like to fork the repository and install my version. How do I do it? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838061/671013), but I'm too new to Ruby and failed to understand what to do.

**More details:** After installing the gem I found the following script `/usr/local/bin/json_resume`:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby


#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'json_resume' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'json_resume', version
load Gem.bin_path('json_resume', 'json_resume', version)
```

It seems like it calls the gem installed in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json_resume-1.0.4/`. I failed to point it to the forked version of mine.

Answer (score 8):

You should definitely not be modifying the version which is installed system-wide.

Instead, you should:

1. Clone the repository on Github
2. Checkout **your copy** of the source code locally

   ```
   $ cd /home/my_user
   $ git clone git@github.com:/.../my_forked_gem
   ```
3. Use the local copy of the gem's source code in your consuming project's Gemfile instead of the Rubygems-hosted gem:

   ```
   gem 'my_forked_gem', path: '/home/my_user/my_forked_gem'
   ```
4. Modify your local copy in `~/my_forked_gem`, and push to your forked Github repo
5. Issue pull requests against the original project for any features you think are worthy of inclusion in the original gem

Comment: Will step 3 above overwrite the gem's version which was already installed? Or, do I have to manually remove it first?

Comment: No, you don't have to uninstall anything. That's the entire point of using Bundler/Gemfile - it lets you have separate versions of the same gem installed for different apps.

Comment: So how do I know/choose which version is (to be) used?

Comment: @Dror I'm not sure what you mean. If you use `path: /path/to/your/gem`, that's obviously using the locally checked out source. If you don't use `path: /path/to/your/gem` that's using the system-wide one.

Comment: So I can run step (3) above without or with the last part (`path: /path/to/your/gem`) to use the remote/official version or the local one, respectively?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not helpful. Step (3) doesn't install my modified fork. I don't understand how can I use my modified fork.

Comment: For reference: here's my fork https://github.com/drorata/json_resume and this is my `Gemfile` https://github.com/drorata/json_resume/blob/master/Gemfile

Comment: @Dror You need to edit your Gemfile in your **consuming** project, not in the Gem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132743/discussion-between-dror-and-meagar).