# Two versions of the same gem required in Jekyll

Tags: plugins, rubygems, jekyll

I'm working through a gem problem with Jekyll. On adding the plugin `amp-jekyll`, I got this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "fastimage":
 In Gemfile:
amp-jekyll was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
  fastimage (>= 1.8.0)

jekyll-picture-tag was resolved to 0.3.0, which depends on
  fastimage (~> 1.6.4)
```

`fastimage` is tied to `jekyll-picture-tag`, which is on its more recent version. `amp-jekyll` won't go any lower than 1.8.0. I've tried rebuilding and updating this a few ways, but I'm stumped. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - I thought I'd have to get a vendor folder set up, but all I needed to do was fork the gem, update the dependency (pessimistic to optimistic) and reference it in my gemfile, as in [Forking a gem for a Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582728/forking-a-gem-for-a-rails-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) ; it's an older answer, but effective.